# Does Windows ever stop services when resuming from sleep?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, service, sleep

I'm running on windows 8.
Occasionally, when I resume from sleep, my service gets a stop request through the *SCM* (call to `SvcCtrlHandler` with `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP`). I wasn't able to trace the source of this request. Can it possibly be sent by the OS itself, in some scenario?

My two main suspicions right now:

1. If the resume event (`SERVICE_CONTROL_POWEREVENT` of type `PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC`) is taking too long, the OS might stop the service (system logs contain logs referring to this specific service: `A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the [...] The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion`)
2. The OS stops the service because it has been flagged as a problematic service (system logs contain logs referring to this specific service: `service did not shut down properly after receiving a preshutdown control`

Comment: IMHO, I think your service is crashing. Look through the code.

Comment: I see in my services's logs that I receive a SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP request, and only then the service goes down (as it should, given this surprising request)

Comment: Your service might have tried to do something bad, so OS sent the signal to stop it to avoid the further consequences.

Comment: Services run under System account, and they keep running until you have written the code or condition to stop it. OS will not stop it as you are assuming.

Comment: What if the SCM sent a service request just before you put the machine to sleep.  And then instantly timed-out the request when you resumed, perhaps because resuming is slow.  Add logging so you can see this kind of mishap.